# Keep Image aspect-ratio in fullscreen and occupy space BEFORE image has loaded without width: 100% for any viewport WITHOUT OBJECT-FIT

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

The most important thing up front before you jump to the most obvious solution: `object-fit: contain` is no option for me. I need the actual dom element for the `<img>`-tag to be the same size as the visual result.

Using a background-image is also off the table. It must be an `<img>`-tag

---

I want to replicate the behavior in the code example. Open in full screen and resize the browser from landscape to portrait to see what I want.

My issue is: for a page transition using GSAP Flip, I need the fullscreen image to occupy the space before the image has fully loaded. Usually you would just go `width: 100%` on the fullscreen image. But that doesn't work when the viewport aspect-ratio is greater than the image aspect-ratio, where you would then need `height: 100%` and `width: auto`.

In the code example I achieved the desired end result with `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto` – but again: Now the image needs to be loaded to occupy the space. Before that, the  is just 0x0, understandably, because no one is "stretching it"

Phrased differently: I need the image to occupy the correct space, even when the `src` is not set.

I've tried for hours and couldn't come up with a solution to fill the `.fullscreen` div with a box that keeps aspect ratio but grows as large as possible.

I would be absolutely fine to wrap the `<img>` in another container. But even with `aspect-ratio: 2780 / 1900` on this new wrapper, I couldn't get it to work in all viewport aspect-ratios.

```css
.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: purple;
  padding: 20px;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/2780x1900/fff/aaa" width="2780" height="1900"></div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the "page transition using GSAP Flip" is not going to happen without JavaScript - so you might as well _calculate_ the necessary image dimensions using JavaScript as well then, if it can't be solved using CSS alone.